# OrmLite: Advanced where logic

Tags: android, android-sqlite, ormlite

I have these tables in an Android based application where I'm using OrmLite for the database management.

[image]

What I want to have an x number of array list depending on how many of the product type FOLDER I have.

So in this case I want to a list of products where the productId equals parentId.
So I want a list where

```
 if(productType = FOLDER) {
    if(productId = parentId){
       //add product
    }
 }
```

Basically what I want to end up with, in this case three lists with each containing a list of products where parentId is the same for every product.

I've tried many things, and some works better than others, but a code I want to run actually throws a nullpointer.

```
DatabaseHelper dbHelper = getHelper();
List<Product> productsParents = null;
try {
    Dao<Product, Integer> dao = dbHelper.getDao();
    PreparedQuery<Product> prepQu = dao.queryBuilder().where()
        .eq("parentId", dao.queryBuilder().selectColumns("productId").where()
            .eq("productType", ProductType.FOLDER).prepare()).prepare();
    productsParents = dao.query(prepQu);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    ...
}
```

This code isn't working because productParents returns null, and it does not do what I want, even though it's a slight hint.  If someone know how to do this in code that would be sufficient also, or more likely a mix of java and ormlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a chance to RTFM around building queries?  The [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) docs are pretty extensive:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/query-builder

Your problem is that a prepared query cannot be an argument to the `eq(...)` method.  Not sure where you saw an example of that form.

So there are a couple ways you can do this.  The easiest way is to do a different query for each `productType`:

```
Where<Product, Integer> where = dao.queryBuilder().where();
where.eq("parentId", parentId).and().eq("productType", ProductType.FOLDER);
productsParents = where.query();
// then do another similar query again with ProductType.PRODUCT, ...
```

If you want to do just one query then you can get all products that match the `parentId` and then separate them using code:

```
Where<Product, Integer> where = dao.queryBuilder().where();
where.eq("parentId", parentId);
productsParents = where.query();

List<Product> productFolders = new ArrayList<Product>();
List<Product> productProducts = new ArrayList<Product>();
...
for (Product product : productsParents) {
    if (product.getProductType() == ProductType.FOLDER) {
       productFolders.add(product);
    } else if (product.getProductType() == ProductType.PRODUCT) {
       productProducts.add(product);
    } else ...
}
```

Comment: What I was looking for and I love the abbreviation RTFM.

Comment: RTFM is old school.  Lot of newer hackers don't even know it @JoakimEngstrom.  :-)